# How to embed Power BI Q&A?

Tags: javascript, angular, powerbi-embedded

I'm embedding the Microsoft Power BI Q&A but getting error on console below are the attached screenshot for embed configuration and error.

embed configuration and error

[image]

I followed the **https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#** link for embedding the Q&A but getting error.

Answer (score 1):

`tokenType = 1` in your config suggests EmbedToken which is generated via /GenerateToken API call.
try either changing tokenType to 0 (TokenType.Aad) or retrieving this token using:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt784614.aspx

or this tutorial:
https://guyinacube.com/2017/09/get-embed-token-power-bi-dashboards-reports/

Comment: I tried GenerateToken api for Q&A and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of analysis, I found the answer.

- First generate the token to call the GenerateToken api for Q&A.
- method type **post** https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/your_group_id/datasets/dataset_id/GenerateToken

**Body:-**
`{
  "accessLevel": "view"
}`

**Response:-** `{
  "@odata.context":"http://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/your_group_id/$met...GenerateTokenResponse",
  "token":"H4sI........A=",
  "tokenId":"951b6385-d004-42e4-84a1-e45d904bfca0",
  "expiration":"2018-05-10T08:08:33Z"
}`

**Embed Configuration:-**

```
       var embedUrl = 'https://app.powerbi.com/qnaEmbed?groupId=your_group_id';
       var config = {
                    type : 'qna',
                    tokenType : models.TokenType.Embed,
                    accessToken :  token, // from the above api call
                    embedUrl: ,
                    datasetIds: datasetIds,
                    viewMode : 0, // 0 = Interactive , 1 = readonly
                    question: your_question
                };`
```

- Get the reference of html element where you want to embed Q&A chart.
  `var qnaContainer = $('#qnaContainer');`
- Embed the QNA and display it within the div container

`var qna = powerbi.embed(qnaContainer, config);`